# What kind of control panels do you build as part of your asp.net web application to monitor it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Some of the good panels is ELMAH to see errors and ISIS to check if dlls are deployed in debug mode. Any other panels or dashboards that you are using to monitor a production web asp.net application that will be useful. I personally see a web based log monitor very useful. This will save the reliance on operations and will increase the speed at which we can troubleshoot issues.

What are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Peter's Input Security, part of the DES suite: http://www.peterblum.com/DES/InputSecurity.aspx

I use it to log errors (and automatic mail sending of error logs), and logging and detecting of application attacks, e.g. sql injection, etc.